# Python How to create an update-able plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, user-interface, plot

Im not sure this is the right question or wording so feel free to suggest edits!

Now, my problem is this: Suppose we have an algorithm, a long running one such as training a machine learning model like a neural network, so the code kind of looks like this:

```
for training_iteration in range(training_iterations_num):
    model.train()
```

Now, I want to plot the result of the training after each evaluation so the code should in theory become something like this:

```
for training_iteration in range(training_iterations_num):
    model.train()
    score = model.evaluate()
    plot.add_point_to_plot(x=training_iteration, y=score)
```

This is for a long running algorithm that will be run for longer periods of time, overnights or even a few days so we need a viable way to observe it's evolution.

Matplotlib does not offer, as far as I know, a convenient way to do this. Of course it has APIs for animation and the such but this is NOT what I need. This is a loop in which the train method takes 90-99% of the CPU time, and there is no way to know how long one round of training takes, it is gonna take however long that pile of linear algebra in the background needs to take.

I need some way to plot the evolution of an algorithm during the execution of that algorithm. The main thread of the process will obviously be busy doing the computations so it should not give me a "not responding" like GUIs usually do when you hog their thread and it should support easily adding data to an existing graph/line to show the evolution of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html). What this will allow you to do is to have the training running one thread, and the plot in another. To send the data from the training model to the plot, you can use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#module-queue). Together, the code would look something like this:

Model thread:

```
for training_iteration in range(training_iterations_num):
    model.train()
    score = model.evaluate()
    data_queue.put(score)
```

Plot thread:

```
while(true):
     if not data_queue.empty():
         plot_data.append(data_queue.get())
     plot.display(plot_data)
```

You can then use the plot thread to update the plot as needed.

Comment: Tye plot thread is in an infinite loop running at full speed checking the queue over and over. The plot thread is still saturated.